# Tuple index out of range : Audio to spectrogram

Tags: python, numpy, spectrogram

I am trying to run an audio to spectrogram script, namely:
https://github.com/grrrr/nsgt/tree/master/examples
When I try `python spectrogram.py myaudio.wav`
I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "spectrogram.py", line 111, in <module>  
coefs = assemble_coeffs(c, ncoefs)  
File "spectrogram.py", line 27, in assemble_coeffs  
out = np.empty((ncoefs,cq0.shape[1],cq0.shape[2]), dtype=cq0.dtype)  
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Please advise! :)

Comment: Check `cq0.shape`

Comment: Sorry, im not the best at python....check it in what way?

Answer (score 0):

you can run it with just the argument `--matrixform` added.

I suggest you to see this [issue](https://github.com/grrrr/nsgt/issues/15)! from the github project it can help you

Comment: Hmm, it seems to not do anything at all...nothing happens. I've also tried with --scale=log as well, but that gives me the same tuple error. This is with a small 5 second wav file. When I try longer wav files I get the different message: "format not usable"

Comment: Also to mention, I'm getting the message "nsgt.ftt is falling back to numpy.fft" not sure if that matters?

Comment: It finished for the 5 sec clip, but came with more errors:  https://pastebin.com/DstvxxCB  It also used 30% of my CPU.